# Why does httpJSON fail, but httpLBS succeeds?

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

This function (with httpLBS) works:

```
makeRequest = do
  response <- httpLBS "http://httpbin.org/get" 
  putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)
```

But this function (with httpJSON) does not:

```
makeRequest = do
  response <- httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get" 
  putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)
```

It throws the error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `httpJSON' prevents the constraint 
`(aeson-1.1.2.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON a0)' from being solved.
          Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Compare the types of `httpLBS` and `httpJSON`:

```
httpLBS ::   MonadIO m              => Request -> m (Response ByteString)
httpJSON :: (MonadIO m, FromJSON a) => Request -> m (Response a         )
```

Notice that `httpLBS` *always* produces a `Response ByteString`, but `httpLBS` produces `Response a`. What does that mean?

In this case, it means that `httpJSON` can produce a `Response` containing anything at all with a `FromJSON` instance, and it’s up to the function’s *caller* to decide. How does the caller decide? By specifying the type! This is one of the most interesting properties of Haskell’s typeclasses: the behavior of your program is determined by its *types*.

Of course, most of the time, you don’t see those types, because they are inferred. For example, if you write the following program, you will not need to write any type annotations:

```
ghci> id True
True
```

Even though the `id` function has type `a -> a`, GHC can infer that there is clearly only *one* choice for `a`, `Bool`, so it is chosen. However, consider your program—how can GHC know what `a` is supposed to be? The `response` result is only used in one place, `getResponseStatusCode`, which has the following type signature:

```
getResponseStatusCode :: Response a -> Int
```

This function also works on *any* `Response a`, so GHC still can’t decide what the `a` should be: according to GHC’s terminology, the `a` variable is **ambiguous**. The trouble is that picking a specific type for `a` is necessary, since it needs to know which `FromJSON` instance to use to parse the response body.

In order to solve this problem, you can disambiguate the expression by supplying your own type annotation, forcing GHC to pick a particular type for `a`:

```
makeRequest = do
  response <- httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get" :: IO (Response ())
  putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++ show (getResponseStatusCode response)
```

Of course, you should replace `()` with whatever type represents the structure of the JSON you expect the response to produce.

Comment: Thank you for such an amazing answer. It works, and it helps me understand why!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful for anyone else but it helped me. I tried the `::IO (Response ())` annotation and I was getting back the full printed response and then `"expected (), encountered Object"`, and switching it to `:: IO (Response Object)` fixed it to simply output

```
λ makeRequest
200
it :: ()
```